# Call a JSF method

Tags: jsf

When user clicks the Testscript button, the method testscript should be called. But it calls a different method in my bean. Following is the sample code.

```
 <h:form id="myform">
<h:commandButton id="testScript" actionListener="# {ScriptedPolicyBean.testScript"} />
    <feat:Button onclick="document.getElementById("myForm:testScript")" />
     </h:form>
```

Please help

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: please paste your testscript button html, script, and the method gets called, and the method needs to be called instead.

Comment: <h:form id="myform">
<h:commandButton id="testScript" actionListener="# {ScriptedPolicyBean.testScript"} />
    <feat:Button onclick="document.getElementById("myForm:testScript")" />
     </h:form>

Answer (score 0):

Doing onclick="getElementById" does nothing but simply gets an id. As it is a button and you do not say "return false;" your form is submitted by the feat button (if it has the type submit on the rendered page). Of course in this case the actionlistener of the other button is not called at all (as it has nothing to do with the form submit).

You should call the click method on the testScript button like this: onclick="document.getElementById('myForm:testScript').click();".

It would be nice to have a simple <input type="button" /> instead of the feat:button to be sure the submit is not called by that element.

Comment: I tried your option. But it still calls the other method from the bean. Please help

Comment: If you could provide the code of your bean and the full namespace of "feat" that could help a lot. Or feat is a namespace that you defined?

Comment: Did you edit the question. It seemed to me last evening that the problem occures when you click on feat:button. From the current description of the question it seems to me that the problem occures when you push the h:commandButton.

Comment: And some more hints: If you copy-pasted the code, please notice that there is a space after # that should not be there. Another hint is to take out a h:messages element onto the page. It happens very often that there is a validation error on the form (so actionListeners are not called) but there is nothing in the log about that. With <h:messages globalOnly="false" /> you can print out all validation problem.