# passing alert() to backing bean causes exception

Tags: jsf

I have a textarea. When user enters 'alert()' in the text area and hits submit button, the page causes exception on the page and the method that shud have been called when user hits submit button is not called. For anything other than 'alert()' it works fine.

Exception message is - Validation Error: One of the URL parameters include javascript.

```
    <h:textarea id="abc" value="ModifyScriptBean.data"  />
    <h:commandButton   id="finishButton"  style="display:none;" action="#{ModifyScriptBean.finish}" >
        <f:verbatim><feat:Button label="Finish" onclick="submitFinishButton()"/></f:verbatim>
    </h:commandButton>
     <script>
    function submitFinishButton() { 
       document.getElementById('resultForm:finishButton').click();
    }
     </script>
```

Comment: You'll probably get help faster if you provida a complete, working example that demonstrates your problem. If it's to long to put into the question, upload it somewhere and add a link.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<textarea id="abc" value="ModifyScriptBean.data"  />
```

To

```
<h:inputTextarea id="abc"  value="ModifyScriptBean.data"/>
```

Comment: @ParagPhadtare post the xhtml I can't tell what you are doing just from the snippet. Update your code then because I'm seeing `textarea`

Comment: @ParagPhadtare What JSF version are you using ? Is there a reason why you need `f:verbatim` ? According to this post it's not needed anymore after JSF 1.2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471783/call-a-jsf-method